# How to set `default data type` in Gnuradio?

Tags: gnuradio

Every time I add `noise source` block to flow graph,manually change data type `complex` to `float`.
Is there any way to set `default data type` like `samp_rate`?

Comment: you have to realize `samp_rate` is just a variable – like every other variable. Data type is not at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such option for this.
This idea may be implemented in the future on the demand of the community, but the change must be done not in the core program of the GNU Radio, but on the GNU Radio GUI.
GNU Radio uses circular buffers between the blocks to provide a seamless data stream. The data type that you assign is actually the data type of the buffer.